# Spring Exception: MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException

Tags: spring, exception

I'm getting and exception that I do not understand. I have a controller, it gives me back a news object and it appears in the Console, so getting the actual news object is not the problem,

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/viewonestatus/{id}")
public ModelAndView viewOneStatus(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {

    System.out.println("!!!!!! STATUSUPDATECONTROLLER: viewOneStatus : Empezamos con el ID del Anuncio: " + id);

    StatusUpdate status = statusUpdateService.get(id);

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    System.out.println("!!!!!! STATUSUPDATECONTROLLER: viewOneStatus : Empezamos con el ID del Anuncio: " + status);

    modelAndView.getModel().put("status", status);

    modelAndView.setViewName("viewonestatus");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

.... but when try to execute the JSP it gives me the following error, even with an almost empty JSP, like....

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

hello world

Exception: Exception: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Long]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: &#034;viewonestatus&#034;
        Failed URL: http://localhost:8080/viewonestatus/viewonestatus
        Exception message: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Long]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: &#034;viewonestatus&#034;
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: The url looks odd.  You are using `viewonestatus` twice. Are you sure it should not be something like `http://localhost:8080/viewonestatus/1212112`  ??

Comment: the mapping is expecting a long and you're passing /viewonestatus/viewonestatus <- should be long

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/viewonestatus/{id}")
public ModelAndView viewOneStatus(@PathVariable("id") Long id)
```

Here you are declaring a path variable named "id" and you declare its type as Long.
Nextly you are calling url:

```
http://localhost:8080/viewonestatus/viewonestatus
```

the second "viewonestatus" is obviously not a Long type and this is why spring is throwing an exception because it can't convert "viewonestatus" to Long

your reqeust should look like

```
http://localhost:8080/viewonestatus/12321
```

Comment: The problem was that I forgot to include the new jsp into the Tiles.xml. Thanks for the hint that made me look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this was driving me nuts for about 1/2 hour. If you're using SpringBoot, this could help you.

I realized in my controller I was using

`@Controller`

in stead of

`@RestController`

That was it. Ugh.